# deploying to a vps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, unicorn, rbenv

I'm trying to deploy my app and getting this error with `capistrano deploy:cold`. Any ideas?
My environment includes `ubuntu 12.10`, `postgresql`, `rbenv-installer`, `unicorn`.

```
 * executing "cd /home/deployer/apps/microv/releases/20130210112032 && bundle install --gemfile /home/deployer/apps/microv/releases/20130210112032/Gemfile --path /home/deployer/apps/microv/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["192.xx.xxx.xxx"]
    [192.xx.xxx.xxx] executing command
 ** [out :: 192.xx.xxx.xxx] sh: 1: bundle: not found
    command finished in 228ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deployer/apps/microv/releases/20130210112032; true"
    servers: ["192.xx.xxx.xxx"]
    [192.xx.xxx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 227ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/deployer/apps/microv/releases/20130210112032 && bundle install --gemfile /home/deployer/apps/microv/releases/20130210112032/Gemfile --path /home/deployer/apps/microv/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on 192.xx.xxx.xxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find solution add this at the top of deploy.rb require "bundler/capistrano" set :default_environment, { 'PATH' => "$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" }

Answer (score 1):

Try to log in your remote server and find out if there is a `bungler` installed , like this :

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Comment: find solution add this at the top of deploy.rb

    require "bundler/capistrano"
    set :default_environment, {
    
    'PATH' => "$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
    }

Comment: I am glad to hear it. Good luck with your app.